# How to pass the changed state from child component to its parent in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, state

I am trying to understand how to pass a changed state from child component to its parent in `ReactJS`? so far the following code changes the child state but not the parents state, any clue what I am doing wrong?

I am using `redux` to get product array from `mongodb`.

Product array example:

```
[
    {
        “_id”: “2331”, 
        “department”: “Shoes”,
        “category”: “Shoes/Women/Pumps”,
        “name”: “Calvin Klein”,
        “title”: “Evening Platform Pumps”,
        “description”: “Perfect for a casual night out or a formal event.”,
        “style”: “Designer”,
        "colors": ["red","yellow","red","black"]
    },

    {
      “_id”: “30671”, 
      “department”: “Shoes”,
      “category”: “Shoes/Women/Pumps”,
      “name”: “zara”,
      “title”: “Evening Platform Pumps”,
      “description”: “Perfect for a casual night out or a formal event.”,
      “style”: “Designer”,
      "colors": ["red","yellow","red","black"]
    }
]
```

Parent Component

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'

  class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        products: [],
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.getProducts();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (this.props.product.products !== prevState.products) {
        this.setState({ products: this.props.product.products });
      }
    }

    onUpdateProducts = (e) => {
      const newProducts = this.state.products;
      this.props.updateProductName(newProducts);
    };


    render() {
      const { products } = this.state;

      if (isEmpty(products)) {
        productContent = (
          <div>
            <p className="lead text-muted">Error Empty Products </p>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        const productArr = products.map((product) => (
          <Child key={product._id} product={product} />
        ));

        productContent = (
          <div>
            {productArr}
          </div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <div className="container">
          {productContent}
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <button className="btn " onClick={this.onUpdateProducts}>
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    product: state.product
  });

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getProducts,updateProductName
  })(Parent);
```

Child Component

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'

  export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        product: this.props.product,
      };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (this.props.product !== prevProps.product) {
        this.setState({
          product: this.props.product
        });
      }
    }

    onChangeProductName = (e) => {
      const newProduct = Object.assign({}, this.state.product, {
        name: e.target.value
      });

      this.setState({ product: newProduct }, function() {
        console.log('onChangeProductName: ', this.state.product);
      });
    };

    render() {
      const { product } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          <TextInput
              placeholder="Product Name"
              name="prd_name"
              value={product.name}
              onChange={this.onChangeProductName}
            />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you are doing wrong, the solution would be to delete the state from these component, and handle the product name changes by redux => dispatch an action each time the user modify the input, it could be even easier to implement by using a library like `redux-form`

Answer (score 1):

A simple example would explain the concept of passing the changed state from child to the parent.

Component A:

```
export default class A extends Component{

  //This is a callback
  handleStateChange = (value) ={
    console.log("value", value);//you get the value here when state changes in B(Child) component
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <B handleStateChange={this.handleStateChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Component B:

```
export Class B extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
       value: "01"
    }
  }

  handleButton = () => {
     const value = "02";
     this.setState({
       value: "02"
     });
     this.props.handleStateChange(value);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleButton} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Or you can directly pass the state if you call this.props.handleStateChange(this.state.value); this in render directly on any event handler if you want to pass updated state

As @Ying zuo mentioned you need to use redux to get the changed state value of child component in parent component.

When state changes in child component, you make a redux action call by passing the value as param and set that in the state in reducer and get the state in your parent component

Hope that explains the concept.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for a child component to update the parent component:

1. Without using Redux, you can pass a function as a prop of the child component, so the child component can call this function to update the parent component.
2. Store the data in the Redux store. The child component dispatches an action which updates the Redux state, where the parent component gets data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the child a function.

In the child component you are setting state to be equal to props value, and then you are updating state. This has no connection to parent class - you also shouldn't modify props just as an aside.

The solution is to pass a function from the parent to child. This function will update the parent state, and because you are passing the parent state to the child, it will also be updated.

So in your parent class you could do something like:

```
onChangeProductName = (value, i) => {
  const new_product_array = [...this.state.products];
  new_product_array[i].name = value;

  this.setState({ products: new_product_array});
};
```

You would need to pass this to the child

```
const productArr = products.map((product, i) => (
   <Child
      key={product._id}
      product={product} onChangeName={this.onChangeProductName.bind(this)}
      index={i} />
));
```

And then call it in the child

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Product Name"
  name="prd_name"
  value={product.name}
  onChange={() => this.props.onChangeName(product, this.props.index)}
/>
```

The child component then doesn't need all the state tracking.